# Why can't I use inherited references outside a target on ant (1.8.1)?

Tags: ant, reference

All I want to do is set a reference to a path on a parent build.xml and use it on a child build.xml (called with `<ant>`). Here's the simplest example I could create:

**build-parent.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="parent" default="do-parent">
    <target name="do-parent">
        <path id="inherited.path"/>
        <ant antfile="build-child.xml" inheritrefs="false" inheritall="false">
            <reference refid="inherited.path"/>
        </ant>
    </target>
</project>
```

**build-child.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="child" default="do-child">
    <pathconvert property="converted.path" refid="inherited.path"/>
    <target name="do-child"/>
</project>
```

I run `ant.bat -f build-parent.xml` 
and get: *Reference inherited.path not found.*

If I change **build-child.xml** to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="child" default="do-child">
    <target name="do-child">
        <pathconvert property="converted.path" refid="inherited.path"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

It works fine...

Obviously I could work around this in several ways, but I wanted to do this the proper way.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here you have shown a solution by calling it from a target. What are the several other ways you were referring?

Comment: @Baishakh, what I was looking for was a way of getting ant to work with the initial version of build-child.xml.  I though maybe there was a special flag on the <ant ..> task, or some command line option.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior has been encountered before:

[Passing References from Master Build File to Child](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/Passing-References-from-Master-Build-File-to-Child-td1343346.html#a1343347)

I couldn't find anything that suggests whether this behavior is by design.

Comment: I guess all I did was create a "canonical" example of that.  If you run the "good case" with -d it is clear that build-child.xml is parsed before the reference is added and thus cannot work.